What happens if you increase the rank of a Stone card?
The description of a Stone card says it has "no rank or suit". The Strength tarot card says it "Increases rank of up to 2 selected cards by 1."
What happens if I use the Strength Tarot card on a Stone card? Does the rank increase get remembered if the Stone card is later cleared of its enhancement?


The rank increase of the Strength Tarot is applied to cards with the Stone enhancement, although it remains a Stone card when it is used. It behaves just like the other card modifiers in this regard.
I tested this to make sure, converting a 4 of diamonds:

I then applied the Strength Tarot to the Stone 4 of diamonds and a non-enhanced 2 of clubs.

Here you can see the Stone card and two 3 of clubs.

I then used a Devil Tarot on the Stone card.

After using the Devil Tarot on the Stone card, we are left with a Gold 5 of diamonds, which verifies that Stone cards behave like cards with the other modifiers.

